# Can't get 'Form' working in Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, mobile-website

I am creating a site using Django/Python. I have only just begun the registration page where a user will input their info and the data should flow into the sqlite3 DB which comes with Django. I have since yesterday evening (been just under 24 hours now) trying to figure out why my forms aren't showing up. I tried attaching what I'm getting vs what I'm aiming for but don't have enough reputation points so
please visit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yfjhLKL-_5Q 9.09mins for what I'm aiming for.  Please note: The word 'welcome' on the youtube vid has been replaced with 'Thank you' by me. This code is in my views.py.

The issue is that the small boxes which a user would type in their fullname and email in the video (which I have replaced with Profession, first_name, last_name etc) are not appearing at all...  instead I am getting just 'Thank you' appearing along with my 'username' (jmitchel3 equivalent) and registration button but no request for text boxes.  My code is below.

I initially thought that my forms were setup incorrectly so I compared my code to the page that's successful and no luck.  I did the same for models but couldn't see anything there either ...

```
models.py:

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Register(models.Model):

    Profession = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 120, unique = True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    instgram_ID = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    facebook_ID = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    twitter_ID = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    forms.py

    from django import forms

from .models import Register

class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = Register
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone_number', 'instgram_ID', 'facebook_ID', 'twitter_ID']

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        email_base, provider = email.split("@")
        domain, extension = provider.split('.')
        #if not domain = 'USC':
        #   raise forms.ValidationError("Please make sure you use your USC email.")
        #if not extension == "edu":
        #   raise forms.ValidationError("Please use a valid .EDU email address")

            #return email

        def clean_full_name(self):
            full_name = self.cleaned_data.get('full_name')
            #write validation code.
            return full_name

        admin.py

        from django.contrib import admin

    # Register your models here.

    from .forms import RegisterForm
    from .models import Register

    class RegisterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ["__unicode__", "timestamp", "updated"]
        form = RegisterForm
        #class Meta:
        #   model = Register
    )

    admin.site.register(Register, RegisterAdmin

views.py

from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import RegisterForm
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    title = 'Welcome'
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
    "title": title, 
    "form": form 
    }

    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        if not instance.full_name:
            instance.full_name = "Justin"
        instance.save

    context = {
        "title": "Thank you"
        }

    return render(request, "home.html", context)

home.html:

<h1>{{title}}</h1>

{{ user }}
{{ request.user }}

<form method ='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}

{{ form }}

<input type='submit' value = 'Register'>

<!-- <input> type='text'> -->
<!-- <input> -->

    </form>
```

It's been a while since I have been on here so if I need to add anything else, let me know..

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about the problem. Are you saying that there are no fields visible on the admin page for Register? There is nothing in this code that prints 'Welcome', so there must be some other code somewhere.

Comment: Hey @DanielRoseman thanks.  My sister said the same thing. I think I am a tad reliant on the images to explain which I'm unable to add.  The word 'welcome' on the youtube vid has been replaced with 'Thank you' by me.  This code is in my views.py. The issue is that the small boxes which a user would type in their fullname and email (which I have replaced with Profesion, first_name, last_name etc) are not appearing at all ..  I have added my views.py and home.html code also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an indentation error. The part where `context` is replaced iwth just `{"title": "Thank you"}` should be indented within the `is_valid()` block. Where it is now, it is replacing the earlier definition of context, which has the result that you're not sending the form to the template.

Comment: Amazing.  That's precisely it.  It works! Wow that took me ages, I am not actually too familiar with the indentation error so thanks a mil.  Tried to vote the answer up but won't allow me to.  Appreciate it